# Slack Slash Command YouTube Embed

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm writing a Slack custom slash command in an Express server. What I'd like is for my Slack command to embed a link to Eurpoe's Final Countdown along with a media link like this:

[image: Final Countdown]

Currently, I'm sending my response like this:

```
  response.send({ "text": "<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw>" });
```

This works, but only pastes the links without any preview.

[image: Final Countdown]

I tried following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702874/slack-slash-command-image-not-unfurling) and adding some unfurl flags, but it didn't seem to help.

```
response.send({
  "text": "<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw>",
  "unfurl_links": true,
  "unfurl_media": true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works fine, but maybe not in the way you expect.

When you post the link to a channel for the first time it will always unfurl the youtube link (with default settings). However, if you post the same link to the channel a 2nd time it will show the link only and not unfurl it. This is standard Slack behavior and as far as I know you can not change it. (unless you want to add a custom unfurling method, which you can do [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling)).

But I can provide you with a small hack to mitigate this Slack feature.

All you need to do it provide a different link every time you post to the same Slack channel. That way Slack will think its a new link and unfurl it. For example you can just add `&dummy={timestamp}` - with `{timestamp}` being the current time in UNIX epoch - to you link and you get an unfurl every time.

You can of course use any query parameter here as long as it does not conflict with any parameter supported by Youtube.

Example:

`"text": "<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw&dummy=1570709500>",`